# PySpark - Creating a timestamp column from two numeric columns containing date and month

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark_session = SparkSession(sc)
>>> mydf = spark_session.createDataFrame(data=[(2018, 1), (2019, 4), (2018, 3), (2019, 4), (2018, 2), (2020, 1), (2020, 4)], schema=['myYear', 'myMonth'])
>>> mydf
DataFrame[myYear: bigint, myMonth: bigint]
>>> mydf.show()
+------+-------+
|myYear|myMonth|
+------+-------+
|  2018|      1|
|  2019|      4|
|  2018|      3|
|  2019|      4|
|  2018|      2|
|  2020|      1|
|  2020|      4|
+------+-------+
```

and versions:

```
$ pip3 list | grep 'spark'
pyspark             3.4.1
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_372-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)
```

I would now like create a timestamp column from these two columns, representing a timestamp of a year and month.

pandas equivalent would be:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> mydf3_pd = pd.DataFrame(data=[(2018, 1), (2019, 4), (2018, 3), (2019, 4), (2018, 2), (2020, 1), (2020, 4)], columns=['myYear', 'myMonth'])
>>> mydf3_pd.loc[:,'year-month'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf3.loc[:,'myYear'].astype(str) + mydf3.loc[:,'myMonth'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
>>> mydf3_pd
   myYear    myMonth year-month
0    2018          1 2018-01-01
1    2019          4 2019-04-01
2    2018          3 2018-03-01
3    2019          4 2019-04-01
4    2018          2 2018-02-01
5    2020          1 2020-01-01
6    2020          4 2020-04-01
>>> mydf3_pd.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   myYear      7 non-null      int64         
 1   myMonth     7 non-null      int64         
 2   year-month  7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2)
```

I tried [`pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) with `format='yyyyMM'` among other combinations and got incomprehensible error messages both the time.

Along with "year-month", I would also like to do the same thing for an integer column containing quarter numbers, "year-quarter". How do I do both of them with pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `to_date()` function for this case.

- `concat_ws('-',<cols>)` - concat year,month with `-` delimited.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(2018, 1), (2019, 4), (2018, 3), (2019, 4), (2018, 2), (2020, 1), (2020, 4)], schema=['myYear', 'myMonth'])
df.withColumn("year-month",expr("to_date(concat_ws('-',myyear,mymonth))")).show(10,False)
#+------+-------+----------+
#|myYear|myMonth|year-month|
#+------+-------+----------+
#|2018  |1      |2018-01-01|
#|2019  |4      |2019-04-01|
#|2018  |3      |2018-03-01|
#|2019  |4      |2019-04-01|
#|2018  |2      |2018-02-01|
#|2020  |1      |2020-01-01|
#|2020  |4      |2020-04-01|
#+------+-------+----------+
```